# try to change color of a single <tag> element but not registering

Tags: html, css

i have a html tab tag that i want to customize i want this tab to have blue text so it stands out from the other tags that have black texts. how do i do that i tried several thing like style="color: ....etc inside the tag. i also put a new little css method in the todc-bootsrap.min.css but i cant put class="new css method name" here. i saw this which bolds a heading when clicked on

```
.nav-tabs > li > a {
color: #666;
border-radius: 2px 2px 0 0;
 }
```

i also see this which turns them all to a color which i may need just need to rename it something unique to i can apply it to only that tab

```
.nav-tabs > li > a {
color: #666;
border-radius: 2px 2px 0 0;
}
```

this is the code in full
    
    
        
            
                
                    
                        Requisitioner
                        
                    
                    
                        Requisition Date
                        
                    
                    
                        Required Date
                        
                    
                    
                        Buyer

```
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Vendor</label>
                    <input value="{{req.vendor.vendorName}}" class="form-control" type="text" readonly="readonly" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-lg-8">
        <div class="row ">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Total</label>
                    <input value="{{req.amount | currency}}" class="form-control" type="text" readonly="readonly" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row ">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Description</label>
                    <textarea rows="8" value="" class="form-control" type="text" readonly="readonly">{{req.description}}</textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <br />
            <label ng-show="req.bidWaiverCheck"><b><mark>*This requisition has a bid waiver tab*</mark></b></label>
        </div>
    </div>
</tab>
<tab heading="Items">

    <div class="hide-xs hide-sm col-md-12 col-lg-12">

        <div class="row">
            <!--Added the Account Number field -->
            <div class=" col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-1 text-center"> Item #</div>
            <div class=" col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-1 text-center"> PO Price</div>
            <div class=" col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-1 text-center"> Quantity</div>
            <div class=" col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-1 text-center"> UOM</div>
            <div class=" col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-1 text-center"> Est. Price</div>
            <div class=" col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-1 text-center"> Account Number</div>
            <div class=" col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3 text-right"> Description</div>


        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default" ng-repeat="item in req.items">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <!--Added the Account Number field -->
                <div class=" col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-1 text-left"> {{item.itemNumber}}</div>
                <div class=" col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-1 text-left"> {{item.poPrice | currency}}</div>
                <div class=" col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-1 text-left"> {{item.quantity}}</div>
                <div class=" col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-1 text-center"> {{item.UOM}}</div>
                <div class=" col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-1 text-right"> {{item.total | currency}}</div>
                <div class=" col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-2 text-left"> {{item.accountNumber}}</div>
                <div class=" col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-5 text-right"> {{item.description}}</div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</tab>

    <tab class="nav-tabss newclass" ng-show="req.bidWaiverCheck" heading="Bid Waiver" >

<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
    <div class="row ">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Requisitioner</label>
                <input value="{{req.requisitioner.fullName}}" class="form-control" type="text" readonly="readonly" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Buyer</label>
                <input value="{{req.buyer.fullName}}" class="form-control" type="text" readonly="readonly" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Requisition Number</label>
                <input value="{{req.requisitionNumber}}" class="form-control" type="text" readonly="readonly" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>P.O. Number</label>
                <input value="{{req.poNumber}}" class="form-control" type="text" readonly="readonly" />
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Total Value</label>
                <input value="{{req.amount | currency}}" class="form-control" type="text" readonly="readonly" />
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Reason Code and Description</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" rows="4" value="" type="text" readonly="readonly">{{req.reasonCode}} </textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-lg-8">
    <div class="row ">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-8 col-xl-8">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Vendor & Vendor ID</label>
                <input value="{{req.vendor.vendorName }} ({{req.vendorID}})" class="form-control" type="text" readonly="readonly" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row ">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-8 col-xl-8">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Vendor Address</label>
                <input value="{{req.vendorAddress}}" class="form-control" type="text" readonly="readonly" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row ">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-8 col-xl-8">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input value="{{req.vendorCity}}, {{req.vendorState}} {{req.vendorZip}}" class="form-control" type="text" readonly="readonly" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row ">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Items</label>
                <textarea rows="5" class="form-control" ng-repeat="item in req.items" type="text" readonly="readonly">{{item.description}}</textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row ">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Justifications</label>
                <textarea rows="5" value="" class="form-control" type="text" readonly="readonly">{{req.justification}}</textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!--<approvals parent-object="req"></approvals>-->
</tab>

<tab heading="Documents">
    <documents parent-object="capitalRequest"></documents>
</tab>

<tab heading="Approvals">
    <approvals parent-object="req"></approvals>
</tab>
```

[image]

Comment: can't you just give the tag a class, then select it in your css file?

Comment: Why you don't add an id for the the element you need?

Comment: show your html please

Comment: this is the element 
        <tab class="nav-tabss" ng-show="req.bidWaiverCheck" heading="Bid Waiver" >

Comment: i tried to make a new class nav-tabss but it didnt register

Comment: @Edgar did you try adding a class like `<tab class="nav-tabss newclass">`?

Comment: i tried but that did not work

Comment: what do you mean "did not work"?

Comment: Post all of the code relevant code you're using so we know what problem you're talking about.

Comment: ok. i posted full html file. and i inspect element and it seems that it is uses todc-bootstrap.min.css for its styling. but when i make a new class similar to the one its already using i just add a letter or something and it will default to original even if i use class="some class name i made" in the <tab> tag

Comment: also the word "tab" in the tag has a swiggly green line under it saying it is an unknown element and cannot be placed here. but its always been there, so i dont know if that has issues coming from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add a class to the element

`<tab class="nav-tabss blue" ng-show="req.bidWaiverCheck" heading="Bid Waiver" >`

in your css call the class

`.blue{color: blue !important;}`

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mm6ck3dc/15/

I am not quite sure what you are trying to target however just move the "blue" class to whichever tab you want.

Comment: this did not work for me. i believe that todc-bootstrap.min.css is overwriting my " class="nav-tabss blue" " section in my tab tag

Comment: @Edgar Then create an `id="blue"` and call using `#blue{color: blue !important;}`

Comment: i added a screenshot of what im looking for that "bid waiver" tab i want to be blue.

Comment: Did you try adding the id?

Comment: i did, this is my tab tag <tab id="blue" ng-show="req.bidWaiverCheck" heading="Bid Waiver"> and i replace the "." with a "#". but doesnt work for me :(

Comment: Who knows then, you will need to post the html that has to do with that tab.